# send id to popupwindow

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor

I have this :

```
foreach (var user in Model.Users){
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="#name"  class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">user.UserName</a>
    </td>
</tr>}
```

and need send id (@user.id) to

```
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="email" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
@using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeName", "Person"))
{

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Person.UserName, "Jméno", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label align-center" })
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.Person.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Person.UserName, " ", new { @class = "text-danger " })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Upravit" class="btn btn-success" />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Zavřít</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And then sed it to the controller.

I need use id the right user in the controller.
Has anyone some ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden field to store user id value in it to push the user id to controller action.
for e.g

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.User.Id)
```

or

```
<input type="hidden" id="UserId" value="@user.id"/>
```

Comment: It's good tip for me. But still not help me. I send down the code. My problem is send "Id" in one cshtml file from foreach to code outside foreach. Now I moved PopUp window inside foreach and Id is "1" for everybody.

Comment: <a href="#name" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal"><input type="hidden" id="UserId" value="@user.Id"/>@user.UserName</a> this I try after you answer.

Answer (score 0):

In this code  Id = 1 for everybody

```
<td>
<a href="#name" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal"><input type="hidden" id="UserId" value="@user.Id" />@user.UserName</a>

<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="name" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
            <div class="lr">
                <div class="rl">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h2>Změna jména @user.Id</h2>
                        <hr class="star-primary">
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeName", "Person", new { id = user.Id }))
                        {
                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


                            <div class="form-horizontal center-block">
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <h4>Zadej nové jméno</h4>
                                    <hr />


                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.UserName, "Jméno", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label align-center" })
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.UserName, " ", new { @class = "text-danger " })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                            <input type="submit" value="Upravit" class="btn btn-success" />
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Zavřít</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```